# Using Gmail API to get Message Body with formatting

Tags: javascript, php, parsing, gmail-api

I have spent a few weeks on this now so I though I would ask the experts. I have a PHP script that reads a message via the Gmail API Client Library:

```
    $optParamsGet2['format'] = 'full';
    $message = $Service_Gmail->users_messages->get('me',$messageId,$optParamsGet2);
    $snippet = $message->getSnippet();
    if(strlen($snippet) >= 90){ $snippet=substr($snippet, 0, 90); $snippet="$snippet..."; }
    $headers = $message->getPayload();
    $vardumpresult=serialize($headers);

    try {
        $parts = $message->getPayload()->getParts();
        $body = $parts[0]['body'];
        $rawData = $body->data;
        $sanitizedBody = strtr($rawData,'-_', '+/');
    }
```

I then sending the $sanitizedBody to a Javascript modal and converting to base 64

```
var mail_body = _self.data('body'); 

// Create Base64 Object
var Base64={_keyStr:"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",encode:function(e){var t="";var n,r,i,s,o,u,a;var f=0;e=Base64._utf8_encode(e);while(f<e.length){n=e.charCodeAt(f++);r=e.charCodeAt(f++);i=e.charCodeAt(f++);s=n>>2;o=(n&3)<<4|r>>4;u=(r&15)<<2|i>>6;a=i&63;if(isNaN(r)){u=a=64}else if(isNaN(i)){a=64}t=t+this._keyStr.charAt(s)+this._keyStr.charAt(o)+this._keyStr.charAt(u)+this._keyStr.charAt(a)}return t},decode:function(e){var t="";var n,r,i;var s,o,u,a;var f=0;e=e.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g,"");while(f<e.length){s=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));o=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));u=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));a=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));n=s<<2|o>>4;r=(o&15)<<4|u>>2;i=(u&3)<<6|a;t=t+String.fromCharCode(n);if(u!=64){t=t+String.fromCharCode(r)}if(a!=64){t=t+String.fromCharCode(i)}}t=Base64._utf8_decode(t);return t},_utf8_encode:function(e){e=e.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");var t="";for(var n=0;n<e.length;n++){var r=e.charCodeAt(n);if(r<128){t+=String.fromCharCode(r)}else if(r>127&&r<2048){t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>6|192);t+=String.fromCharCode(r&63|128)}else{t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>12|224);t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>6&63|128);t+=String.fromCharCode(r&63|128)}}return t},_utf8_decode:function(e){var t="";var n=0;var r=c1=c2=0;while(n<e.length){r=e.charCodeAt(n);if(r<128){t+=String.fromCharCode(r);n++}else if(r>191&&r<224){c2=e.charCodeAt(n+1);t+=String.fromCharCode((r&31)<<6|c2&63);n+=2}else{c2=e.charCodeAt(n+1);c3=e.charCodeAt(n+2);t+=String.fromCharCode((r&15)<<12|(c2&63)<<6|c3&63);n+=3}}return t}}

// Decode the String
var decodedString = Base64.decode(mail_body);
$("#mail_body").text(decodedString);
$(_self.attr('href')).modal('show');
```

When I display the email body in a modal it shows up like this:

This is a test message.  This is a second paragraph.  This is a third paragraph.  This is formatting bullets: - bullet 1 - bullet 2 - bullet 3 *Chris Rose* Math Teacher / Technology Learning Consultant Hamilton High School, Hamilton City School District 1165 Eaton Avenue Hamilton, OH 45013

How can I sent/print to my modal div with proper formatting?

Comment: dont use `$().text();`...use `$().html();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your jQuery. You are using `.text()`. Which strips out all html tags. If you want to keep the formatting use `.html()` to set the content.

SO change this:

```
$("#mail_body").text(decodedString);
```

to this:

```
$("#mail_body").html(decodedString);
```

Since you mention that the alert box is formatted correctly. I believe you have escaped character for newlines and indents in your decoded String.

First add this to your CSS for the `mail_body` div:

```
#mail_body{
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

this will take care of newline characters. IE8+.

You will need to figure out which other escape characters are in the string and replace them, however you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help but unfortunately I am getting the same result. It is interesting that when I paste the 
(This is a test message. This is a second paragraph. This is a third paragraph. This is formatting bullets: - bullet 1 - bullet 2 - bullet 3) into StackOverflow it converts it with proper returns and spacing.

Comment: It's in the original post. I use: var decodedString = Base64.decode(mail_body); I am calling the previously defined Base64 in the original post.

Comment: @ChristopherRose no, right after you have that code: `var decodedString = Base64.decode(mail_body); `. Add this line: `alert(decodedString);`. and run the code. You will get a popup. Paste the contents of that in your question.

Comment: It is properly formatted! The alert box detects the formatting. Here is an email from twitter:

Thanksgiving — the day we express gratitude for family, food and football. (But mostly football.) Thankfully, new #NFL features on Twitter will keep you in the center of the action, no matter where you celebrate.

Explore #NFL (https://twitter.com/ExploringBird/timelines/482300495508168704)

**Get in the game.**



Now I just need to figure out why its not sending the correct formatting using $("#mail_body").html(decodedString); to the div or why it is not displaying correctly in the div.

Comment: @ChristopherRose the alert box did not have any html tags around its content?

Comment: The alert box displayed the correct formatting. The problem has to be related to $("#mail_body").html(decodedString); sending to a div. When I send decodedString to a div, the div does not display the text with formatting.

Comment: To explain further the alert box didn't show any html tags, just displayed the message in the correct format.